# Are policies concepts?

Tags: c++

While working through Section 1 of **Modern C++ Design** (Alexandrescu, 2001) the following thought occurred to me: aren't policies just concepts?

If I understand correctly, a concept is a set of requirements on the interface of the classes implementing the concept.

A policy is also a specification that policy classes must satisfy. (though some policy classes can provide an enriched interface, I am not sure whether this takes a policy out of the realm of being a concept)

Comment: Someone voted to close the question. Any comment?

Comment: Not my vote but it was _unclear what you asking_. Maybe you should improve your question by giving a better explanation what should be considered a policy or a concept.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ These are not my terms. I gave definitions only to make sure that my question is not based on wrong assumptions, but really the question stands even if the two last paragraphs are deleted.

Comment: I'm well aware these aren't your terms, I know the book, but not every one does. You may consider to add a citation at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is it better now?

Comment: Not much to be honest.

Comment: Well, a policy is typically a class that has to meet certain requirements. But there is no universal concept of "being a policy"  other than in this purely descriptive sense, and the requirements on a particular policy are dictated by their use in one specific parameterized consumer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added the citation, but in any case the question is probably relevant only to the readers familiar with the mentioned concepts. Questions do not normally provide all the background needed to understand the question. E.g. someone who asks a question on multiple inheritance would not define what he means by `inheritance` and by `multiple` and by `virtual look-up`, would he? So, please explain how you think the question should be improved.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg You misunderstood what I meant by citation probably. Not where you've got the source of the policy term from, but adding an explanation from there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then what did you mean by the words "at least"? Also, please see the rest of my last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider what are the aims of both concepts and policies.

Concepts establish strong assumptions about the class, both syntactically and semantically. For example, `Comparable` implies presence of comparison operators for the type as well as that certain axioms hold, i.e. `a == b -> a is equivalent to b`, rather than any other implementation of `operator==`. Strong assumptions make code more predictable.

Policies, on the other hand, establish the actual behaviour of the class, with an emphasis on interchangeability. Every individual implementation of a policy does encompass one or more concepts; however, the variations of a policy that you plug into a class only share constraints. For example (pseudocode):

```
// constraint Lockable -> has Lock() and Unlock() methods

// concept RealLockable -> constrained by Lockable, Lock() blocks other threads
// concept FakeLockable -> constrained by Lockable, Lock() does nothing

class FakeLock; // a policy that embodies the concept FakeLockable
class Lock; // a policy that embodies the concept RealLockable
class RecursiveLock; // a policy that can also embody the concept of RealLockable

template<class T, Lockable Lock> // constrained by Lockable
class Queue;
```

A policy is an implementation technique to alter the behaviour of a target class. A concept is an explicit tool for establishing assumptions:

```
template<Comparable T>
class PriorityQueue;
```

`Comparable T` would not be a policy, in my opinion, because when you specify `PriorityQueue<int>` or `PriorityQueue<double>` you don't aim to change the behaviour: on the conceptual level, all these queues do is allow you to access min or max element in constant time. However, with some future syntax you can claim that `T` embodies mathematically correct semantics, i.e. `a < b -> b > a`, and then `Comparable T` will be a concept.

In the end, every class, policy or not, represents a concept or two. Classes introduce concepts implicitly, concepts document them explicitly.

Comment: Aren't concepts also implicit in the sense that there is no syntax to enforce them?

Comment: In the previous explanation, I confused myself with concepts and constraints. Hope that it is more clear now.

Comment: Also, I think that some tools could be provided in the future to enforce some of the concepts, if they are clearly specified.

Answer (score 1):

As far as what I understood from that book, *policy based design* isn't absolutely precise about a distinction from *concepts*. Merely because the latter term came up later historically.

Alexandrescu's policies are an early predecessor of what's understood as concepts nowadays.

Though there's a line:

Concepts won't ever change instantiation layout, while policies as introduced in the book could.

Somewhat I think a concept describes an interface, while a policy might participate in an interfaces implementation.